# TextView: How to prevent displaying the action menu when selecting text in TextView?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-actionmode, action-menu

I have a selectable TextView.
I want to prevent showing the context menu when selecting text.

I implemented this code but action bar and context menu still is displayed.

```
   tv.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Return true to ensure the yourTextView is still selectable
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Remove all action items to provide an actionmode-less selection
            menu.clear();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {

        }
    });
```

How can it be remove forever?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            menu.removeItem(android.R.id.selectAll);
            menu.removeItem(android.R.id.cut);
            menu.removeItem(android.R.id.copy);
            menu.removeItem(android.R.id.paste);
            menu.removeItem(android.R.id.replaceText);
            menu.removeItem(android.R.id.shareText);
            return true;
        }
```

Try to manually remove item from the menu. I hope it should work now.

Comment: it doesn't work and the text is not selected. I also want to select the text.

Comment: it still doesn't work. I tested it on API 21 (Android 5.0).

Comment: The action bar is still displayed.

Comment: @ArmanHosseini If you do not want `ActionBar`, you need to extends your style from `Theme` having no `ActionBar`. I am confused that you are referring to an `ActionBar` or `ActionMode` which is temporarily overlayed in the `ActionBar` when selecting items.

Answer (score 0):

I thought and finally wrote the following code:

```
    tv.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            removeActionBar(getWindow().getDecorView());
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {

        }
    });

    private void removeActionBar(View v) {
            ViewGroup viewgroup = (ViewGroup) v;

            for (int i = 0; i < viewgroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View v1=viewgroup.getChildAt(i);
                    if ( v1 instanceof ViewGroup )
                            removeActionBar(v1);
                    if ( v1 instanceof ActionBarContextView ) {
                            viewgroup.removeView(v1);
                    }
            }
    }
```